# Paypal subscription trial extra charge?

Tags: paypal

I tried to implement paypal pro for my site. Which will let user enter their info and charge 1$ for the trial, and 10$ for the recursive fee.

But when I check my merchant account, it show up 1$ and 10$ in separate order, but within 1 day (it charge 10$ that I don't want)

```
PROFILEID=I%2d0xxxxxx1HCKEF
&PROFILESTATUS=PendingProfile
&TRANSACTIONID=0NP43842KS810000T
&TIMESTAMP=2010%2d05%2d16T18%3a56%3a55Z
&CORRELATIONID=89adac79d0d6
&ACK=Success
&VERSION=57%2e0
&BUILD=1298200
&METHOD=CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile
&VERSION=57.0
&PWD=1274sss7
&USER=sand_12sdsad7629_biz_api1.dital.com
&SIGNATURE=IacdATZe5XHmKJs1n2w3uWMRDWyaOGDb
&PAYMENTACTION=Sale
&AMT=10
&CREDITCARDTYPE=Visa
&ACCT=4804270925925835
&EXPDATE=052015
&CVV2=243
&FIRSTNAME=
&LASTNAME=
&STREET=223232323
&CITY=3232
&STATE=IA
&ZIP=5452
&COUNTRYCODE=US
&CURRENCYCODE=USD
&BILLINGPERIOD=Month
&BILLINGFREQUENCY=1
&PROFILESTARTDATE=2010-05-6+02%3A56%3A57
&INITAMT=10
&FAILEDINITAMTACTION=ContinueOnFailure
&DESC=Recurring+%2410
&AUTOBILLAMT=AddToNextBilling
&PROFILEREFERENCE=Anonymous
&TRIALBILLINGPERIOD=Day
&TRIALBILLINGFREQUENCY=5
&TRIALAMT=1
&TRIALTOTALBILLINGCYCLES=1
&SALUTE=Mr.
&EMAIL=dsads%40dsads.com
```

Was there any problem with this query string?

Comment: Did you really want to advertise that credit card number, expiry date, and cvv2 so publically?  I would hope those are not real.

Comment: These are fake, ofcourse. These are for sandbox.paypal.com. :) no worries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with this part of the PayPal process (I still use IPN), but this line looks suspect:

> &INITAMT=10

I believe that should be AMT.

From the [PayPal Documentation](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_CreateRecurringPayments):

> INITAMT: Initial non-recurring payment
>   amount due immediately upon profile
>   creation. Use an initial amount for
>   enrolment or set-up fees
>
> AMT:  Billing amount for each billing
>   cycle during this payment period. This
>   amount does not include shipping and
>   tax amounts

So, by using INITAMT, you are charging them the $1 for the initial trial period plus a $10 enrollment fee.  This does not sound like what you want.

Comment: I see. Your answer perfectly solve the problem here. Just remove the INITAMT and everything is fine.